# What is the purpose of taxi-cabs and buses in Pixar’s 'Cars 2' movie?

Tags: cars, cars-2

I recently had the chance to watch Pixar’s Cars 2. Although the story is located in a pure imaginative universe, there is an issue that goes beyond any (even imaginative) logic.

When the story is set in London, we can see a lot of cabs and double-deckers buses moving around the city streets.

So I was wondering: **What the purpose of these vehicles?** Obviously they're too small to carry other vehicles... And if they aren't able to carry vehicles, then precisely what is the aim of their “uniform” and why are they in the city at all?

[image]

Comment: You might as well ask why cars themselves exist -- they have doors, windows for those inside, but nothing exists to go inside them. It is a question that has long been mused over by the philosopher Aristhrottle.

Comment: Out-of-universe reasons: [1](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/71CrtwsT5CL._SY355_.jpg) and [2](http://www.amazon.com/Disney-Pixar-Cars-Disneystore-Exclusive/dp/B00CJEQ0E0/). Of all the Pixar franchises, Cars has probably [the strongest dependence on merchandising](http://articles.latimes.com/2011/jun/21/business/la-fi-ct-cars2-20110621). So whatever gets the sales going is allowed.

Comment: @Trevel - Ah yes, the famous pupil of the philosopher Archimercedes.

Comment: @Richard Socartes. Immanual Transmission Kant. Porphyry of Tire. Somebody stop me.

Comment: @trevel - Karl "skid" Marx? Jean Wheel-Jacques Roussea? Baruch Wheelspinoza? Albert Camshaft?

Comment: @richard  I'm afraid your memory is off.  Aristhrottle was Plageot's student (who was of course Socartes's student)

Comment: Why do they need to have a purpose?  Do human beings (or types of human beings) need to have a purpose to exist in our world?  They exist because car-evolution didn't select against them?  I guess evolution in the world of Cars is not just natural selection, if cars are actually designed by other cars, though, so it's a fair question.

Comment: mattel thinks that cars fit into the double decker just fine: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jncNe5aUVeM

Comment: @flup - Most of them, anyway.

Comment: @flup: Actually Mattel cars fit in double decker because the size of the latter is wrong (too big). It’s a scale matter...

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Within the logic of Cars, buses act as mobile billboards, as well as providing guided tours of London

> *I love the detail in our films. I believe God is in the details. We
>   put so much detail into this film. The more you look, the more you’ll
>   see of car parts, car shapes. Every sign, every street name,
>   everything… **Every ad on the sides or on the buses or things like this
>   are all unique to the car world** and unique to whatever country you’re
>   in.* - <sub><sup>[John Lasseter](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/10/18/movies/john-lasseter-of-pixar-defends-cars-2.html)</sup></sub>

[image]

And both buses and taxis would be able to ***lead*** cars to their desired destinations in return for a small fee.

> No one knows the sites, streets or shortcuts of London better than the
>   jovial Chauncy Fares, a quintessential London black cab. - <sub><sup>[Pixar Wiki](http://pixar.wikia.com/wiki/Chauncy_Fares)</sup></sub>

Comment: Interesting and exhaustive answer! Therefore, in short and easy terms: in the Cars universe (London) buses are intended as a kind of sandwich (man)  car promoting touristic places, while cabs are intended as a kind of living GP? :)

Comment: @Lo.Ve. - Well, we know from Cars that only some (well off) vehicles have  GPS. It stands to reason that other cars need to ask directions or, in this case, rent a guide.

Comment: And buses, being taller, can lead more cars...

Answer (score -1):

It's part of the comedy to defy the logic of that universe. On one hand they have to display a certain image of the "human" London to create a believable/similar/familiar "cars" London and on the other hand they break that very image by showing the difference between the status/function of a human and a car.